# Deno.land WS module not found

Tags: deno

I'm trying to set up a WebSocket server with [deno](https://deno.land). I've seen that there is / was a ["ws"](https://deno.land/std@0.117.0/ws) module in the standard library of deno, but in the current version there isn't one anymore.

Should I use the old std library or has this module moved somewhere else?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71133383/438273) has the correct information. You might also want to keep an eye on the development of [`WebSocketStream`](https://web.dev/websocketstream/). (It's [already implemented](https://doc.deno.land/deno/unstable@v1.18.2/~/WebSocketStream) in Deno unstable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ws` was deprecated and then [removed](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/releases/tag/0.118.0) in `std@0.118.0`, It is recommended to use [Deno.upgradeWebSocket](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable@v1.18.2/%7E/Deno.upgradeWebSocket) instead to upgrade incoming HTTP requests to WebSocket connections.

Here is an example of a basic WebSocket server and client in Deno (inspired by [this post](https://deno.com/blog/v1.12#server-side-websocket-support-in-native-http)):

```js
// server.js

async function handleConn(conn) {
  const httpConn = Deno.serveHttp(conn);
  
  for await (const e of httpConn) {
    e.respondWith(handle(e.request));
  }
}

function handle(req) {
  if (req.headers.get("upgrade") != "websocket") {
    return new Response("not trying to upgrade as websocket.");
  }

  // Upgrade the incoming HTTP request to a WebSocket connection
  const { socket, response } = Deno.upgradeWebSocket(req);
  socket.onopen = () => console.log("socket opened");
  socket.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log("socket message:", e.data);
    socket.send(new Date().toString());
  };
  socket.onerror = (e) => console.log("socket errored:", e.message);
  socket.onclose = () => console.log("socket closed");

  return response;
}

const listener = Deno.listen({ hostname: "localhost", port: 8080 });

for await (const conn of listener) {
  handleConn(conn);
}
```

```js
// client.js

const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");

// Connection opened
ws.addEventListener('open', function (_event) {
    ws.send('Hello Server!');
});
```

expected output on server after running client.js:

```
socket opened
socket message: Hello Server!
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But I don't understand, what "upgrade WebSocket" is meaning. I want to connect to the server via `new Websocket("ws://myserver.de")`.

Comment: WebSocket connections are created using an initial HTTP request/response pair. Clients can send an upgrade header with their request to tell the server they want to establish a WebSocket connection. `Deno.upgradeWebSocket` is used on the server to upgrade incoming HTTP requests with an upgrade header to WebSocket connections. Hope this clarifies things, I updated the answer with some example code for a WebSocket server + client code